# SendGrid API Substitutions not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I created a simple email dynamic transactional email template in SendGrid with only tag "First_Name".

When I DO NOT use a substitution everything works fine i.e. I get an email. But when I do use a substitution the email fails. Here is the code that uses substitution.

```
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
personalization.Substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"First_Name","Don" } };

        var msgs = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            TemplateId = "d-123",
            From = new EmailAddress("info@domain.us", "Name"),
            Subject = "Account is ready",
            ReplyTo = new EmailAddress("info@domain.us", "Name"),
            Personalizations = new List<Personalization>() { personalization },
        };
        
        msgs.AddTo(new EmailAddress("user@email.com"));
        msgs.AddBcc(new EmailAddress("admin@domain.us));
        msgs.SetClickTracking(true, true);

        var responses = await client.SendEmailAsync(msgs);
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: If I recall, you need to create the custom field if it is not one of the built in fields provided by SendGrid. Did you create the "First_Name" custom field in the SendGrid portal?

Comment: Yes. I have created a custom field in the SendGrid portal.

Comment: Found the solution, followed as mentioned here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#send-multiple-emails-with-personalizations

From the transactional templates section